# Find out sandbox.open(url,null.....) execution time

Tags: javascript, php, dom-events, jaxer

I am using `Jaxer.Sandbox.open(url,null,openOptions);` method to fetch url contents. I want to find out time required to fetch url content. If this process took long time say more than 6 seconds, then custom error page should display.

Comment: And your question is...?

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question right,

```
var sandbox = new Jaxer.Sandbox(url,null,options);
if(sandbox.waitForCompletion(5000))
  {
    // Page loaded
    return {contents:sandbox.toHTML()};
  }
  else
  {
    // Took too long
    return {error:"Request Timed Out"};
  }
```

That should do the trick.